# Html is rendering White space with line break

Tags: html, css

I have 2 div tags :

1. where starting and closing of div tag is in the same line.

```
<div>Same line</div>
```

[image]

It renders the correct output "Same line" without any space in the beginning and end of the text

2. where starting and closing of div tag is in multiple lines.

```
<div>
    Next Line
</div>
```

[image]

It render the output " Next Line " with space in the beginning and end of text.

I want to use 2nd way for formatting purpose.  I am not sure why is it taking extra spaces.

How can I make div definition in multiple lines without rendering any extra space in the beginning and end of the text?  I want to do it for my entire application that has ton of div tags so I want to do something globally for my app.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Use the 2nd way of coding, when you finish your project, you can minify all the code with one click: 
https://www.google.com/search?q=html+minifier

Comment: both will produce exactly the same result (https://jsfiddle.net/1mop750a/) unless you are modifying the white space algorithm using the `white-space` property